# How to pull a private docker image from AWS ECR to use with the Testcontainers library in Java

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, docker-registry, amazon-ecr, testcontainers

I am trying to programmatically create and spin up a MongoDBContainer from a docker image hosted in a private AWS ECR repository. This will be used for automated integration tests, will be run locally and within CICD pipelines. But that doesn't work (see 2.). When I pull the image from DockerHub (see 1.) it works.
Code I have so far is:

```
@Testcontainers
@AutoConfigureDataMongo
public interface MongoTestContainer {

  // 1. This pull the image directly from DockerHub, and it works.
  //@Container MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new
  //MongoDBContainer("mongo:5.0.11");

  // 2. This should pull the image from AWS ECR but doesn't work.
  @Container MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new
  MongoDBContainer("<account>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<imageName>:<version>");

  
  @DynamicPropertySource
  static void setProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.uri", mongoDBContainer::getReplicaSetUrl);
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Kind regards,
John

Answer (score 2):

Using the 2nd approach should fail throwing an exception and the message should provide the fix which I would mention below. There are two options:

1. In `~/.testcontainers.properties` add `hub.image.name.prefix=custom.dockerhub.repository/`
2. Use `new MongoDBContainer(DockerImageName.parse("<account>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<imageName>:<version>").asCompatibleSubstituteFor("mongo")`

Comment: To further expand on this correct answer, I assume the issue is not about the actual pulling of the image, but using an unknown image in `MongoDBContainer`.